# Deform 3D Object in SceneKit

Tags: scenekit, blender, modeling

I want to deform the shape of a complex 3D model in an iOS app, is there a way scene kit allows you to deform a mesh around a point or similar? If not what is the best way to create this kind of effect? I have a mesh with armature in Blender, can I use this?